# Python rolling sum taking data from to columns

Tags: python, pandas

The below is a part of a dataframe which consists of football game results.

FTHG stands for "Full time home goals"

FTAG stands for "Full time away goals"

```
  Date       HomeTeam    AwayTeam      FTHG    FTAG    FTR
14/08/93    Arsenal    Coventry       0       3      A
14/08/93    Aston Villa   QPR         4       1      H
16/08/93    Tottenham   Arsenal       0       1      A
17/08/93    Everton    Man City       1       0      H
21/08/93    QPR     Southampton       2       1      H
21/08/93    Sheffield   Arsenal       0       1      A
24/08/93    Arsenal      Leeds        2       1      H
24/08/93    Man City    Blackburn     0       2      A
28/08/93    Arsenal     Everton       2       0      H
```

I want to create a code in python that calculates a rolling sum (for ex. 3) of the goals scored by each team regardless if the team was home or visitor. 
The `groupby` method does half the job. Say "a" is a variable and "df" is dataframe

```
a = df.groupby("HomeTeam")["FTHG"].rolling(3).sum()
```

The result be something like that:

```
         FTHG   
Arsenal  NaN
         NaN
         4.0
        .....
```

However I would like the code to take into account also the goals when Arsenal was visiting team. Respectively to produce a column (it should not be called FTHG but to be some new column)

```
Arsenal  NaN
         NaN
         2
         4
         5
```

Ideas will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can combine those columns together and then apply groupby

```
tmp1 = df[['Date','HomeTeam', 'FTHG']]
tmp2 = df[['Date','AwayTeam', 'FTAG']]
tmp1.columns =  ['Date','name', 'score']
tmp2.columns =  ['Date','name', 'score']
tmp = pd.concat([tmp1,tmp2])
tmp.sort_values(by='Date').groupby("name")["score"].rolling(3).sum()   


name          
Arsenal      0    NaN
             2    NaN
             5    2.0
             6    4.0
             8    5.0
```

Comment: Hi galaxyan, 

The logic and the code seem fine.  My output however ends like that: 
Name   Arsenal    59      NaN, 101     NaN, 186     NaN, 143     NaN, 197     NaN, 0       3.0, 11      3.0
Bear in mind the original data is much bigger. In the first question I posted just an excerpt manipulated by me so that "Arsenal" appears more often and one can get the idea behind my question. So in the original data "Arsenal" appears in the following order 0,11,29,30,34,45. However the output is totally mixed. I also converted the Dates in my table to datetime as I know this is the norm.

Comment: @MartinYordanovGeorgiev what is your question? output is mixed?

Comment: Yes, output is mixed. The sort_values function doesn't seem to do its job. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: Just to clarify - the code provided by galaxyan is perfectly fine and working. I had problems with the dates format but once I fixed it all was working as expected.